# Can I gracefully include formatted SQL strings in an R script?

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I'm working in an R script that uses a long SQL string, and I would like to keep the query relatively free of other markup so as to allow copying and pasting between editors and applications. I'd also like the ability to split the query across lines for better readability.

In the RODBC documentation, the `paste` function is used to build the query out of separate chunks, but I'd prefer something less kludgy and with fewer quotes and commas. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can override the %+% operator to have better string concatination syntax:

```
'%+%' <- function(x,y) paste(x,y,sep="")

y<-"y1"
x<-"somethingorother"
query<-
'SELECT DISTINCT x AS ' %+% x %+%',\n'    %+%
'                y AS ' %+% y %+% '\n'    %+%
' FROM tbl
 WHERE id=%s
 AND num=%d'

cat(query,"\n")
```

yields:

```
> cat(query,"\n")
SELECT DISTINCT x AS somethingorother,
                y AS y1
 FROM tbl
 WHERE id=%s
 AND num=%d
```

Comment: I find shQuote helpful when x or y are strings.

Answer (score 13):

If you're an old C programmer from way back, as I am, you might enjoy just using sprintf().

Borrowing Ian's example:

```
y<-"y1"
x<-"somethingorother"
query <- sprintf(
'SELECT DISTINCT x AS %s,
                 y AS %s,
 FROM tbl
 WHERE id=%%s
 AND num=%%d', x, y)
```

yields:

```
> cat(query,"\n")
SELECT DISTINCT x AS somethingorother,
                 y AS y1,
 FROM tbl
 WHERE id=%s
 AND num=%d
```

Comment: I also like using sprintf for interpolating within multi-line strings.  It is ever-so-slightly reminiscent of how you bind variables to statements in Perl's DBI.  And readable.

Answer (score 8):

A graceful way of *"including"* a long SQL query is to keep it in a separate `.sql` file. Preferably somewhere it can  be syntax highlighted, a text file in RStudio will do the job. You can then in your main R script read the file into a string and populate it with variables using one of the many "named" `sprintf`-type solutions, such as [infuser](https://github.com/Bart6114/infuser).

**.sql**

```
select *
from mytable
where id = {{a}} 
and somevar = {{b}}
```

**.R**

```
library(readr)
library(infuser)

query <- read_file("query.sql") %>%
         infuse(a = 1, b = 2)
```

Comment: A prepared statement is the safer way to do this.

Comment: A prepared statement is also far more efficient in many cases.  If your DB has a caching optimizer, it can use the same execution plan for the same statement with various bound parameters, but if you substitute the parameters directly into the SQL, it will probably have to recompute the plan every time.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend just using a plain string, and not embedding variable values into it.  Use placeholders instead.

```
sql <- "SELECT foo FROM bar
    WHERE col1 = ?
    AND col2 = ?
    ORDER BY yomama"
```

I'm not sure if the double-quote is the best way to embed multi-line strings in R code (is there something like here-docs?), but it does work, unlike in Java.

Is there some reason you don't want to send `"\n"` or `"\t"` to your database?  They should be fine in the SQL.

Comment: How can I bind values to these placeholders? I couldn't find anything in the documentation of RODBC.

Comment: Some drivers seem to support it, some don't.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186015/bind-variables-in-r-dbi .

Comment: RODBC does not support parameterized queries. RODBCext adds this. It sounds like DBI is in the process of adding them.

Comment: Passing a query built as describe here  works fine in RStudio . At the beginning Rstudio says that the string may be an error, since you split it in 4 lines, but when running it, if no empty new lines between line and line, it works like a charm. I use ODBC and to pass arguments to this SQL queries, I use DBI too. Here the tutorial to pass named arguments to the SQL query: https://dbi.r-dbi.org/reference/sqlinterpolate

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up simply hitting the sql string with `sql <- gsub("\n","",sql)` and `sql <- gsub("\t","",sql)` before running it. The string itself can be as long as it needs to be, but stays free of any concatenation markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this easily using [glue](https://glue.tidyverse.org/reference/glue_sql.html), allowing you to write code like

```
glue_sql("
  SELECT {`var`}
  FROM {`tbl`}
  WHERE {`tbl`}.sepal_length > {num}
    AND {`tbl`}.species = {val}
  ", .con = con)
```