# How to use a variable name in a SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, r, variables

I'm using R to call a mySQL statement, where I define the variable outside the statement e.g.

```
foo = 23;
dbGetQuery(con, "select surname from names WHERE age = '.foo.' ;")
```

But this returns an empty set, I've googled around and tried'.&foo.'   ".foo."   '".&&foo."' 
 and many different combinations, but none of them work, I think this should be a mysql question rather than an R specific problem I'm having, but not sure.  Normally variables have $values but not in R.

Comment: Isn't `dbGetQuery` an R function? It looks like an R question, but you've got *both* tags.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I remove the mysql tag.
I think the correct query is something like this, where the var goes a t the end:   dbGetQuery(con, "select od from plate_data WHERE col = '%s'", foo)  But this doesn't work either..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
foo = 23;

sqlStatement <- paste("select surname from names WHERE age =",foo,'"',sep="")

dbGetQuery(con, sqlStatement;)
```

Comment: I'd use 
paste("select surname from names WHERE age =",shQuote(foo),sep="")

Comment: thanks, this also works without the ' '  what are those for Robert?  sqlStatement <- paste("select surname from names WHERE age =",foo,sep="")

Comment: @John. You're correct. The paste function already appends " for you so you don't need '"'. In some instances, when working with strings that have " in them, you can use single ' to wrap the string. This is very useful when dealing with the XML package where strings may have many nested ".

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the answers to this question: [Can I gracefully include formatted SQL strings in an R script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630724/can-i-gracefully-include-formatted-sql-strings-in-an-r-script).

The simplest solution is to use the `paste` command as Robert suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer gives bad advice which leaves your application vulnerable to SQL injection. You should always use bind variables instead of concatenating values directly into your query. Use the `dbGetPreparedQUery` method as described in this answer: [Bind variables in R DBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186015/bind-variables-in-r-dbi)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the semi-colon at the end of query sometimes creates problem. Try changing your query from:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "select surname from names WHERE age = '.foo.' ;")
```

to:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "select surname from names WHERE age = '.foo.'")
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still returns "data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows" where as if I put 23 instead of foo it works fine.

Comment: what do dot character mean '.foo.'?

Comment: I don't know what the dots mean, I was trying a few different things from other languages I found using different formats.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the command has to be a string, so you should append the single components. Not being familiar with R I cant help you out HOW to do that. In MS-VBA the string concatenation operator is '&'.