# Error in using variables in SQL statements

Tags: sql, r, select

Im extracting some data from a table using sql select statment in R,

```
query <- "select * from MyTable where TimeCol='6/29/2012 21:05' ";
result <- fn$sqldf(query);
```

The above code gives correct results, but when the time value is saved in variable, it doesn't works

```
mytime <- "6/29/2012 21:05";

query <- "select * from MyTable where TimeCol = $mytime";     # OR

query <- "select * from MyTable where TimeCol = $[mytime]";   # OR

query <- "select * from MyTable where TimeCol = '$[mytime]' ";

result <- fn$sqldf(query);
```

None of the above three lines is working

`View(result)`   it gives the error:  invalid 'x' argument

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2184318/1281189)

Comment: The string "it doesn't works [sic]" is not a built-in error message in R.

Comment: @BenBarnes im using sqldf query in R to access R dataframes, the link you referred uses dbGetQuery, but it doesn't works for sqldf

Comment: @Jack Maney i've written the error above 'invalid 'x' argument' means sqldf query doesn't returning any thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$[]` and `$()` are not valid syntax and the quotes that were around the time string in the first instance of `query` in the post are missing in the subsequent instances so a correct version would be:

```
library(sqldf)

mytime <- "6/29/2012 21:05"
MyTable <- data.frame(TimeCol = mytime)
query <- "select * from MyTable where TimeCol = '$mytime' "  

fn$sqldf(query)
```

Comment: Ah, OK. I didn't read between enough lines. It wasn't just incorporating variables into SQL statements, but using the specific functionality of gsubfn in conjunction with sqldf. Downvote understood (the downvote on the Q wasn't from me, though).

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer I linked to in a comment uses a different function to query the data.frame, the principle is the same: paste the variable to the rest of your select string, ensuring quotes are included when necessary (using `shQuote`), then pass that character string to your sql querying function of choice.

```
query <- paste0("select * from MyTable where TimeCol = ", shQuote(mytime))

result <- fn$sqldf(query)
```

The semicolons at the ends of your lines probably aren't necessary.

---

As Joran mentions in a comment, `sprintf` could also be used (perhaps with a gain in readability in case there are many variable components in your query string):

```
sprintf("select * from MyTable where %s = '%s'", "TimeCol", mytime)
# [1] "select * from MyTable where TimeCol = '6/29/2012 21:05'"
```

Comment: `sprintf` is another useful option for this sort of thing.

Comment: @joran, good point. Added as alternative.