# Execute Postgres Function in R

Tags: r, postgresql, terr

I am trying to execute a postgres function within R (using Spotfire Terr), however I cant get the syntax to work for dbSendQuery

I have tried both dbGetQuery and dbSendQuery and can't get it to work.  I looked for several examples, but the only ones that I have found are those that have "Insert into" or "UPDATE" statements.  I haven't been able to find how to execute a function.  I saw that it is possible with sql server using sqlExecute (dbcon, "EXEC .....").  Is there something equivalent for Postgres?

so the function does a few insert statements based on 3 parameters that are passed.  Here's what I tried:

```
Name<-'this is a test'
AInteger<-1
BInteger<-2
result<- dbSendQuery(conn, 'select * from "Main"."InsertDataSet"(?,?,?)', list(Name, AInteger,bInteger))
```

the function takes 3 parameters. In postgres database, I call the function with select * from "Main"."InsertDataSet"('a name',123,124).   I figured that it could be called the same way in R...I can't find a diff example, that is otherwise.

I get the following error

TIBCO Spotfire Statistics Services returned an error: 'Error: RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "?"
LINE 1: select * from "Main"."InsertDataSet"?
                                                      ^
)
    eval(expr, envir, enclos)
    eval(expr, envir, enclos)
    dbSendQuery(conn, "select * from \"Main\".\"InsertDataSet\"?",
    standardGeneric("dbSendQuery")
    .standardGeneric("dbSendQuery", structure(function(conn, statement,
    dbSendQuery(conn, "select * from \"Main\".\"InsertDataSet\"?",
    postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...)
    NULL'.
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions.Executors.RemoteFunctionClient.OnExecuting()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions.Executors.AbstractFunctionClient.d__31.MoveNext()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions.Executors.SPlusFunctionExecutor.d__12.MoveNext()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions.DataFunctionExecutorService.d__3.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used the R Postgres package, but going by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201221/how-to-use-parameters-with-rpostgresql-to-insert-data) I can suggest the following:

```
sql <- "SELECT * FROM Main.InsertDataSet($1,$2,$3)"
result <- dbSendQuery(conn, sql, c(Name, AInteger,bInteger))
out <- dbFetch(result)
dbClearResult(result)
```

or more directly

```
out <- dbGetQuery(conn, sql, c(Name, AInteger,bInteger))
```

Comment: i made the change above,but now i am getting an error with my last statement dbDisconnect(conn)  Error in postgresqlCloseConnection(conn, ...) : connection has pending rows (close open results set first)  Am I suppose to send the results somewhere before closing the connection?

Comment: OK what is this Postgres function doing?

Comment: I used dbGetQuery instead of dbSendQuery and it now works without any errors.  Thanks!!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I assumed a little by editing your question, hope I didn't go too far.

Comment: @r2evans Not at all, I appreciate your help.  The OP's original attempt to bind a list seemed off to me, so I tried to dig around.