# RPostgreSQL - Passing Parameter in R to a Query in RPostgreSQL

Tags: r, parameter-passing, rpostgresql

**Question**: How do I pass a variable in the RPostgreSQL query?

**Example**: In the example below I try to pass the date '2018-01-03' to the query

```
library(RPostgreSQL)

dt <- '2018-01-03'

connect <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), 
                 dbname="test",
                 host="localhost",
                 port=5432,
                 user="user", 
                 password="...")
result <- dbGetQuery(connect,
                "SELECT * FROM sales_tbl WHERE date = @{dt}")
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131569/proper-way-to-pass-parameters-to-query-in-r-dbi) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201221/how-to-use-parameters-with-rpostgresql-to-insert-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `paste0` to generate your query and pass it to dbGetQuery:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)

dt <- '2018-01-03'

connect <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), 
  dbname="test",
  host="localhost",
  port=5432,
  user="user", 
  password="...")

query <- paste0("SELECT * FROM sales_tbl WHERE date='", dt, "'")
result <- dbGetQuery(connect, query)
```

Comment: Do you know how to handle the case when "dt" is a list of dates or values? e.g. '2018-01-03', '2017-01-03' and so forth.

Comment: Try this:
dt <- c('2018-01-03', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-04') *then*
paste("SELECT * FROM sales_tbl WHERE date =", paste0("'", dt, "'", collapse = " OR date = "))

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection.  An improvement is to use the `dbQuoteString()` or `sqlInterpolate()` functions [see RStudio Best Practices](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/). As far as I know, there is no way to do this with the `dbBind` function that is called by `dbGetQuery(con, sql, params)`, at least for the RPostgreSQL implementation of DBI.

Comment: @ichbinallen: read the answer below if you are still looking to sanitize sql with `dbBind`. Didn't realize I didn't respond to the second part of of your comment previously.

Answer (score 2):

The safest way is to parameterize the query as mentioned [here](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries)

Example:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)

dt <- '2018-01-03'

connect <- dbConnect(drv = PostgreSQL(), 
  dbname ="test",
  host = "localhost",
  port = 5432,
  user = "user", 
  password = "...")

query <- "SELECT * FROM sales_tbl WHERE date= ?"
sanitized_query <- dbSendQuery(connect, query)
dbBind(sanitized_query, list(dt))
result <- dbFetch(sanitized_query)
```

Here by passing `?` you are sanitizing your query to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Another thing I like to do is to create `.Renviron` file to store my credintials. For example, for the connection above, the `.Renviron` file will look like this.

```
dbname = test
dbuser = me
dbpass = mypass
dbport = 5432
dbhost = localhost
```

save the file, restart `RStudio` (to load the `.Renviron` file at startup). Then access the credentials using the `Sys.getenv(variable)`

```
#example:
connect <- dbConnect(drv = PostgreSQL(), 
  dbname = Sys.getenv("dbname"),
  host = Sys.getenv("dbhost"),
  port = Sys.getenv("dbport"),
  user = Sys.getenv("dbuser"), 
  password = Sys.getenv("dbpass"))
```

Comment: what if you have a start date and an end date? how does the query then change?

Comment: have you actually tried this yourself and does it work?

Comment: @kRazzyR yes. You'd need to change your SQL query. Sth like `SELECT * from table WHERE date between "?" and "?"`. Then send the parameter for those "?" placeholders on second parameter like `dbBind(query, list(date1, date2)`. Let me know if that worked for you or not.