# how to pass value stored in r variable to a column in where clause of postgresql query in R

Tags: r, rpostgresql

I am using RPostgresql and DBI in RStudio.

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(DBI)
#save password
prod_pw <- {
  "my_pass"
}

 # make db connection
 con <- dbConnect(RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL(), dbname = 'my_dbname', 
                        host = 'my_host',
                        port = 5432, # or any other port
                        user = 'user_name',
                        password = prod_pw)


# save query
myquery<- 'select count(*), state from results where date=\'2018-11-10\';'


#run query
my_query_stats<-dbGetQuery(con,myquery)
```

However I want to automate this, such a way that

> the date can be either input from the user, or at minimum use the system date at the time of running the script.

What I tried:
ex:

```
 this_date<-Sys.Date()
#or accept from user
this_date<- readline("Please Enter Date\n")  
# Please Enter Date2018-11-30
# this_date
# [1] "2018-11-30"

    myquery<- 'select count(*), state from results where date=this_date;'
    dbGetQuery(con,myquery) # didn't work, null value returned.

myquery<- 'select count(*), state from results where date=\'this_date\';'
    dbGetQuery(con,myquery) # didn't work, null value returned.

 myquery<- 'select count(*), state from results where date=\"this_date\";'
dbGetQuery(con,myquery) # didn't work, returned null value.
```

Please advise on how to accept value from user and send that to the psql query's date field.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51648611/rpostgresql-passing-parameter-in-r-to-a-query-in-rpostgresql) and pay special attention to the alternative suggestion in the comments in reference to sql injection concerns.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/ (*"Oh yes, Little Bobby Tables, we call him"*).

Comment: Does `RPostgreSQL` not take `DBI::dbBind`?

Comment: (If it doesn't, `RPostgres` does ... I don't know for certain what other significant differences might exist.)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
this_date = "2018-11-30"


 string = paste("select count(*), state from results where date= 
 TO_DATE(this_date,'YYYYMMDD')")

 rs = dbGetQuery(connection,string)
```

Comment: have you tried this? I get the following error `Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  column "this_date" does not exist`. I think the paste is not working so the value of this date is not going into the `string` variable.

Comment: Yes, and it runs successfully.