# how to use parameterized query using R and Rpostgres so as to accept values contained in a variable as input to the psql

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I want to pass values contained in variables as inputs to a postgresql query using R.

**Currently I'm following where it gives as example:**
https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/

```
Using a parameterised query with DBI requires three steps.

You create a query containing a ? placeholder and send it to the database with dbSendQuery():

airport <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM airports WHERE faa = ?")
Use dbBind() to execute the query with specific values, then dbFetch() to get the results:

dbBind(airport, list("GPT"))
dbFetch(airport)
##   faa            name      lat       lon alt tz dst
## 1 GPT Gulfport-Biloxi 30.40728 -89.07011  28 -6   A
Once you’re done using the parameterised query, clean it up by calling dbClearResult()

dbClearResult(airport)
```

**Here is my current setup.**

```
install.packages("RPostgres")
#https://github.com/r-dbi/RPostgres
require(RPostgres)
require(DBI)
require(tidyr)
# RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL()

# make connection
con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), dbname = 'test', 
                      host = 'mydbtest.com',
                      port = 1234, # or any other port specified by your DBA
                      user = 'test',
                      password = 'test')

rs = dbGetQuery(con, "select count(*),state from sales where created > ? and created < ? group by state")
```

***What I want to do:***
Pass two dates as inputs to the query.

**Error I get:**

```
> rs = dbGetQuery(prod_con, "select count(*),state from sales where created > ? and created < ? group by state")
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "and"
LINE 1: ...count(*),state from sales where created > ? and create...
```

**Question1** 
How do I get around this error, and what is causing it?   I'm using the ? placeholder as given in the example.

**Question 2**
How do I pass multiple values to the two `?`s
like this

> dbBind(con, list("2019-06-21","2019-06-22")) ?

References:
[how to pass value stored in r variable to a column in where clause of postgresql query in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605747/how-to-pass-value-stored-in-r-variable-to-a-column-in-where-clause-of-postgresql)

[RPostgreSQL - Passing Parameter in R to a Query in RPostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51648611/rpostgresql-passing-parameter-in-r-to-a-query-in-rpostgresql?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4):

**Answer to question 1**

Two reasons why it doesn't work.
The syntax error you get is due to a [known issue](https://db.rstudio.com/databases/postgresql/#known-issues) with RPostgresql. You can resolve by replacing `?` with `$`.

And after fixing the syntax, you must bind the parameters. Refer to fixed version of example in this answer.

**Answer to question 2**

You can pass multiple parameters in a query by appending sequential integers to the `$` signs. ie: `SELECT * FROM table where integercolumn > $1 and stringcolumn = $2`.

Remember to bind those parameters after!

**Fixed version of example posted in question**

```
install.packages("RPostgres")
require(RPostgres)
require(DBI)
require(tidyr)
# RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL()

# MAKE CONNECTION
con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
    dbname = 'test', 
    host = 'mydbtest.com',
    port = 1234, # or any other port specified by your DBA
    user = 'test',
    password = 'test')

# SEND QUERY
rs = dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT count(*), state FROM sales WHERE created > $1 and created < $2 GROUP BY state")

# BIND PARAMETERS
dbBind(rs, list(date1, date2)) # where date1 and date2 are your defined variables or raw date values

# FETCH FROM DB USING QUERY
rows <- dbFetch(rs)

# CLEAR RESULT
dbClearResult(rs)
```

Note that when binding parameters `$1` corresponds to `date1`.

*this is my first stack overflow answer so an upvote would help me a lot if this helps you! -Jake*

Answer (score 2):

Parametrized queries are best done using `bind` -> `send` -> `fetch`.

So Where you have used the `?` expression in your `dbGetQuery`, this would be done in the

```
rs = dbSendQuery(con, "select count(*), state 
                       from sales 
                       where created > ? and created < ? group by state")
```

Then you would Bind your parameters to the Query `dbBindQuery(rs, list(blah, blah))`
Finally you `dbFetchQuery(rs)`.

So your frame work would look like;

```
rs <- dbSendQuery(...) 

dbBindQuery(rs, ...)

dbFetchQuery(rs)

dbClearResult(rs)
```

This can all be found on the Rstudio website (You are using already) [Here](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries) Which you have already noted.

So in response to

Question 1: You bind your parameters in `dbBindQuery` on an object returned from `dbSendQuery` not `dbGetQuery`.

Question 2: I am not as sure on this but your parameters are passed in a list. There are many examples online of people showing how to speed up your Queries with parametrisation. [Here is one such example](https://www.r-bloggers.com/parameterized-sql-queries/)