# Parameterized queries with RODBC

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I have a variable in R that I would like to pass to a database. I *could* use `paste` like many suggest when reading Google results, but that is unsafe because of SQL injection vulnerabilities. I'd rather prefer something like this:

```
x <- 42
sqlQuery(db, 'SELECT Id, Name FROM People WHERE Age > ?;', bind=c(x))
```

Is it possible to use parameterized queries with RODBC? If not, is there an alternative library that supports them?

I'm using SQL Server, RODBC 1.3-6 and R 3.0.0.

Comment: It seems to be mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1645086/142019) as "placeholders" but I still couldn't find how to use them.

Comment: would cleaning the string before pasting it not accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Take a look at the `RODBCext` package

Answer (score 9):

Mateusz Zoltak wrote `RODBCext` package in 2014 (based on work by Brian Ripley and Michael Lapsley):

```
conn = odbcConnect('MyDataSource')

sqlPrepare(conn, "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE column = ?")
sqlExecute(conn, 'myValue')
sqlFetchMore(conn)
```

Source: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html

Comment: Yes - this is a better solution.  Proper parameterization reduces security issues (SQL Injection) and can improve performance due to cached query plans (only important if the query is executed a lot).  As a better software Craftsman pattern - I recommend this kind of solution.