# How to write a parameterized SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I am trying this query to fetch my value from a MS SQL database on basis of two conditions but still I am getting exception in the syntax part.

Can anybody tell me what is the correct way to write a parameterized query in R?

Following is the query I used:

```
query<- paste0("SELECT [value] FROM [RiskDashboard].[dbo].[tbl_Simulation]
                  where Row_Id=", row_id[c(1),] ," AND Script_Id=", script_id[c(1),] ,)

T_data<-sqlQuery(ch,query)

print(T_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Parameterizing data is very important - especially from a security perspective. The examples you have are string concatenations and are subject to SQL injections.

The `RODBCext` package does have support for parameterization.

First - standard SQL parameterization syntax:

```sql
SELECT ColA, ColB FROM MyTable where FirstName = ? and LastName = ?
```

Each `?` mark indicates in order the values that will appear in a vector.  This syntax is true for ODBC regardless of platform. Others have extended to support position. eg. OLEDB supports `@P1`, `@P2` etc.

While maybe not important for your R queries - in a multi-user system parameterized queries execute faster because the query plan is stored by the database-server (true of both Oracle and SQL Server).

To semi-plagiarize from the documentation:

```r
library(RODBCext)
connHandle <- odbcConnect("myDatabase")
data <- sqlExecute(connHandle, "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE column = ?", 'myValue', fetch = TRUE) 
odbcClose(connHandle)
```

Documentation is here:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html

More discussion here: [Parameterized queries with RODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178640/parameterized-queries-with-rodbc)

Answer (score 0):

i got the correct way as follows:

```
query<- paste0("SELECT [Row_Id],[Script_id],[value] FROM 
[RiskDashboard].[dbo].      [tbl_Simulation] where Row_Id='",row_id[c(i),],"'
AND   Script_Id='",script_id[c(i),],"'")
```