# How to perform parameter substitution in SQL queries using R?

Tags: r, rsqlite

Programming SQL-specific stuff in `Python` I've got used to **always** use parameter substitution when executing plain SQL queries, like this:

```
# Never do this -- insecure!
symbol = 'RHAT'
c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)

# Do this instead
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
```

In the `psycopg2` documentation they even write:

> Never, **never**, **NEVER** use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

Now I have to save data into an SQLite database from `R`. I try to do this with the function `dbSendQuery` that accepts only two arguments: connection handler and the query itself. But how can I provide parameters for substitution?!

Googling around I have found (surprisingly!) that in the R community people always suggest to build an SQL query using `paste` and then just feed it to `dbSendQuery`. But what about security and elegance? It seems like nobody cares... I personally don't understand this.

Comment: Why are you reading `psycopg2` docs which is a Postgres API when you are using SQLite?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameterized queries with RODBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178640/parameterized-queries-with-rodbc). See also [How to write parameterized sql query in R programming using Rstudio IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754346/how-to-write-parameterized-sql-query-in-r-programming-using-rstudio-ide)

Comment: I didn't know the `paste` command represented a security concern...

Comment: @cory google "Bobby Tables".

Comment: @HongOoi Right, I know what SQL injection is. That's usually not that big of a concern in the R world as SQL queries aren't usually done interactively by random members of the public, they are done in your own script ran locally. So the question should ask how to sanitize inputs in an sql query or something that doesn't make it seem like this guy is bashing R users as careless and inelegant.

Comment: @Parfait, just because I work simultaneously with Postgres and SQLite in the same project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With RSQLite, you can use `dbGetPreparedQuery` for parameterized queries (i.e., bind values to prepared statements). See [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/RSQLite.pdf). However, you must pass the binded value as a dataframe object:

```
sql <- "SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?"

t <- 'RHAT'
df <- dbGetPreparedQuery(con, sql, bind.data=data.frame(symbol=t))
```

Comment: Oh, thank you @Parfait, that is exactly what I was looking for! I know this doc and I actually used search to find the the word "parameter" inside, but they call this procedure "SQL preparation", so I did't find it.