# Is there a 'cleaner' way to concatenate a query string?

Tags: r, dbi, rodbc, dbplyr

I am passing a query string to a connection and the result should look like this:

```
select game_name, month, count(*) as count
  from device_metrics.mtu_events
 where YEAR = '2019' and month between '07' and '09'
 group by game_name, month
 order by game_name asc, month asc
```

This works fine if I pass the above block as a single string into `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, myquery)`

But the dates are a variable within a shiny app, so I tried to create a function to generate the query string:

```
my_query <- function(start_date, end_date) {
        yr <- year(ymd(start_date))
        month_start <- month(ymd(start_date))
        month_end <- month(ymd(end_date))

        query <- paste0(
            "select game_name, month, count(*) as count
   from device_metrics.mtu_events
   where YEAR = ", yr, " and month between ", month_start, " and ", month_end, 
            " group by game_name, month
 order by game_name asc, month asc")

        return(query)
    }
```

When I call this function and try to query our database with it I get:

> An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. Athena Error No: 372, HTTP Response Code: 1, Error Message: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:15: '=' cannot be applied to varchar, integer

Is there a 'right' way to do this? How can I construct a query string with variables and pass then to `DBI::dbGetQuery()`

Comment: I guess you need `where YEAR = '", yr, "' and  month between '", month_start, "' and '", month_end, "' group_by grame_name, month` because the single quotes around the 'yr', 'month_start', 'month_end' are not in the `paste0`

Comment: Would that be the equivilent as e.g. this further up `month_start <- month(ymd(start_date)) %>% str()`

Comment: I guess the `month(Sys.Date())` returns numeric  Try `my_query <- function(start_date, end_date) {
        yr <- year(ymd(start_date))
        month_start <- month(ymd(start_date))
        month_end <- month(ymd(end_date))

        query <- paste0(
            "select game_name, month, count(*) as count
   from device_metrics.mtu_events
   where YEAR = '", yr, "' and month between '", month_start, "' and '", month_end, 
            "' group by game_name, month
 order by game_name asc, month asc")

        return(query)
    }`

Comment: Have you looked at `glue`/`stringr::str_glue`?

Comment: Frankly, I would prefer to use `DBI::dbBind` with parameterized queries as opposed to doing the quoting and such (https://bobby-tables.com/). (I'm not familiar with Athena's dialect, not sure how well it's supported.)

Comment: If you have to do string-substitution like this, though, I would **much** prefer/recommend the use of `sQuote` for string literals, as that handles mid-string quotes (whereas using the literal `'` does not).

Comment: Some ideas on parameterized SQL queries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26754346/5325862) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16178640/5325862)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two options where we can quote (`'`) the input as a string as `month`, `year` functions return numeric values

```
my_query <- function(start_date, end_date) {
        yr <- year(ymd(start_date))
        month_start <- month(ymd(start_date))
        month_end <- month(ymd(end_date))

        query <- paste0(
            "select game_name, month, count(*) as count
   from device_metrics.mtu_events
   where YEAR = '", yr, "' and month between '", month_start, "' and '", month_end, 
            "' group by game_name, month
 order by game_name asc, month asc")

        return(query)
    }
```

---

Using `sprintf`

```
my_query <- function(start_date, end_date) {
            yr <- year(ymd(start_date))
            month_start <- month(ymd(start_date))
            month_end <- month(ymd(end_date))

            query <- sprintf("select game_name, month, count(*) as count
       from device_metrics.mtu_events
       where YEAR = '%d'  and month between '%02d' and '%02d' group by game_name, month
     order by game_name asc, month asc", yr, month_start, month_end)

            return(query)
        }
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on manual ticks, `sQuote` would be more robust the malformed parameters (and sql-injection).

Comment: @r2evans Yes, but may have to specify thee fancy quote as FALSE `sQuote(1)
[1] "‘1’"`

Comment: Sure, but `options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)` fixes that.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `fn$` from gsubfn to perform string interpolation.  We will use NULL instead of an actual connection and `fn$list` instead of `fn$dbGetQuery` for purposes of reproducibility but you can replace both.  Do not use underscores or dots in names when doing this.

```
library(gsubfn)

yr <- 2019
monthStart <- '07'
monthEnd <- '09'
con <- NULL

fn$list(con, "select game_name, month, count(*) as count
  from device_metrics.mtu_events
 where YEAR = '$yr' and month between '$monthStart' and '$monthEnd'
 group by game_name, month
 order by game_name asc, month asc")
```

It could alternately be done in two steps:

```
query <- fn$c("select game_name, month, count(*) as count
  from device_metrics.mtu_events
 where YEAR = '$yr' and month between '$monthStart' and '$monthEnd'
 group by game_name, month
 order by game_name asc, month asc")
dbGetQuery(con, query)
```