# How to use dynamic variable in RMySQL LIKE Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, r, sql-like, rmysql

I'm trying to create a query my MySQL database using RMySQL. I want to find all queries that contain a variable I provide through R.

For example:

```
z="name"
dbSendQuery(conn, "SELECT Address FROM Test WHERE Business Like '%z%'")
```

Wher conn is my connection to my database, Address and Business are columns in a table Test.

This doesn't work, as this causes the query to search for rows that contain the letter z, rather than what the variable z stands for. Any suggestions?

Comment: PHP Variables start with a `$` and lines of code are terminated with a `;` Suggest you [start here](http://php.net/docs.php)

Comment: Note the other option of using `sprintf` mentioned in comments there.

Comment: Also more general options [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16178640/324364).

Comment: You should consider passing your variables as parameters instead of interpolating them into the string. Something like `dbSendQuery(conn, "SELECT Address FROM Test WHERE Business Like '%?%'", z)` exists in most database querying APIs. This will not only make it easy to pass the parameter, it will also protect you from SQL injection.

Comment: @TannerNelson There is (currently) no general framework for parametrized queries from R. The RSQLite package has supported it for a while, and the general db interface system is currently being rewritten to include that kind of functionality, but generally speaking in R you build the query itself as a string.