# Using alias in sqlQuery RStudio

Tags: r, rodbc, prepared-statement

I want to use a numerical alias in `sqlQuery` in R. For example, when I run:

```
x <- 2017

test <- sqlQuery(tdConnection, paste("SELECT * FROM Table where year=x;"))
```

I get an error:

> Column x not found

Alias works for text, but not for integers. Is there a way to do it for integers?

Comment: You should rather write it this way: `test<-sqlQuery(tdConnection, paste(" SELECT * FROM Table where year=", x))`

Comment: You can also have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178640/parameterized-queries-with-rodbc

Comment: thanks for the response. but what if there is a group by statement after the where statement? test<-sqlQuery(tdConnection, paste(" SELECT * FROM Table where year=x  group by 1;"))

Comment: `paste("beginning of query ", x, " end of query")`

Comment: Thank you, Scarabee! That worked.